# How to set images to a UISearchBar's scope bar items?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uikit, uisearchbar

For the `UISearchBar`'s scopebar I want to set images instead of titles to identify different scopes. I found only  `scopeButtonTitles` method to set titles in the `UISearchBar` class reference. Is there a way to set images for the scopes?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple:

```
// use Appearance proxy:
id temp = [UISegmentedControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil];

UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_img1"];
[temp setImage:img forSegmentAtIndex: 0];

img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_img2"];
[temp setImage:img forSegmentAtIndex: 1];

.....
```